# How can I make a easy workin login with flask

Tags: html, flask, logging

I have this html login

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/login.css">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <div class="row">
            <form action="/form_login" method="post">
            <div class="colm-form">
                <div class="form-container">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="user" id="user">
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="pass" id="pass">
                    <button class="btn-login" type="submit">Login</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    </main>

</body>
</html>
```

with this flask script

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
   return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/login/')
def login():
   return render_template('login.html')

database={'admin':'admin'}

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

how can I make that when I enter the correct username and password it sends me to another website, lets say home.html and when the user or passowrd is incorrect it stays on login.html and shows something saying that the login is invalid

Answer (score 0):

1. When you click the submit button on a form, the contents of the form will get routed to the route specified in `action` (in your case, this is `"/form_login"`). This means you need to have a route handler for `"/form_login"` with a method of `POST`
2. In the route handler for `/form_login`, you'll retrieve the username and password, do validation against the username/password in your DB and then render a page if the post was successful or send the user back to the home page with an error message if login wasn't successful.

A very simple example (note this is just sample code) would be

```
# Code is using flash to send error messages to the user so you have to import it
from flask import flash

app.route("/form_login", methods = ["POST"])
def form_login:
   user = request.values.get("user", None)
   pwd =  request.values.get("pass", None)

   # You can omit this section by making both fields required
   # in your html form 
   if not user or pwd:
     flash("You didn't enter a username or password")
     return render_template("login.html")
   
   # Add code to validate the user name/pwd
   success = <code to validate user name/pwd>
   if success:  
      return render_template("index.html")
   else:
      flash ("Wrong combination of username and password")
      return render_template("login.html")
```

Comment: I don't understand the success part. I just want to check if the user and pwd is the same that I put on the Database. In this case admin:admin. I don't have a a DB

Comment: I don't know what you're using ```database={'admin':'admin'}``` for. My sample code is saying - you should have logic to validate the username and pwd that user submitted. If it passes your validation, it should return a 'truthy' value that you assign to the variable ```success```. You then check if ```success``` is true or false. You can use whatever logic you want including using/not using a variable name but you need to somehow validate that your check has passed in which case you redirect user to the home page and if it has failed, you ```flash``` an error and return user to the login page